# Ошибка при отправке сообщение человеку | discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord, config, random
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def send_invite(ctx,max_age=0,max_uses=0):
    days = max_age * 60
    invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age=days,max_uses=max_uses)
    await ctx.send(invite)
    print(f"invite link = {invite}")
@bot.command()
async def invites(ctx, member):
    day = 10 * 60 * 24

    invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age=day,max_uses=1)
    await member.send(f"Привет я тебя приглашаю на сервер {ctx.guild.name} ")
    await member.send(f"ссылка {invite} у тебя есть время {day}")
bot.run(config.token)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Msi_Pc\Desktop\ \1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Msi_Pc\Desktop\ \1\main.py", line 19, in invites
    await member.send(f"Привет я тебя приглащаю на сервер {ctx.guild.name} ")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Msi_Pc\Desktop\ \1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1349, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Msi_Pc\Desktop\ \1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1023, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Msi_Pc\Desktop\ \1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 238, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Comment: Вероятно проблема в передаваемом параметре `member` в `invites`

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно что вы пытаетесь передать переменной `member`. Если вы хотите написать пользователю в ЛС, то вам необходимо получить пользователя, например:

```
member = ctx.author
```

Таким образом уже написать ему:

```
await member.send(#сообщение)
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто, добавьте аннотацию `discord.Member` к аргументу `member` команды `invites`, чтобы бот получал именно объект участника, а не его строковую версию как по-умолчанию.

```
@bot.command()
async def invites(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    ...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]